# Dynamic Namespaces Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

How can I use dynamic namespaces in socket.io.

I'm looking in the (poor) [documentation](http://socket.io/#how-to-use), and it says that namespaces must be used like this:

`io.of('/news')`

`io.of('/akfda')`

To use a namespace you do `io.of("/namespace")`.

Do I need to register every single namespace in the server? Maybe I want a namespace for dynamic content.

How can I do something like :

`io.of('/:somethign/:id')`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004616/has-anyone-successfully-implemented-a-dynamic-namespace-in-node-socket-io

Comment: From reading the docs and a bit of googling it seems socket.io doesn't have this functionality. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732678/express-socket-io-route-parroting-copying-sharing

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Socket.IO supports 'rooms' (https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms), you can use it instead of namespaces. Also when you need dynamic in routes (and you using express in your app) - best way is to use use route-engine from express box.

- [Best way to do dynamic routing with Express.js (node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344628/best-way-to-do-dynamic-routing-with-express-js-node-js)
- [Using routes in Express-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864626/using-routes-in-express-js)
- http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.routes
- http://shtylman.com/post/expressjs-re-routing/
- http://jordanhoff.com/post/22602013678/dynamic-express-routing

However, if you still think that you need dynamic in namespaces in socket.io, here is small example how it can be implemented:

User-side:

```
var connect = function (ns) {
    return io.connect(ns, {
       query: 'ns='+ns,
       resource: "socket.io"
    });
}

var socket = connect('/user/12');
```

Server-side:

```
var url = require('url');
  , ev = new events.EventEmitter()

// <ns name>: <ns regexp>
var routes = {
  // /user/:id
  'user': '^\\/user\\/(\\d+)$',

  // /:something/:id
  'default': '^\\/(\\\w+)\\/(\\d+)$'
};

// global entry point for new connections
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  // extract namespace from connected url query param 'ns'
  var ns = url.parse(socket.handshake.url, true).query.ns;
  console.log('connected ns: '+ns)

  //
  for (var k in routes) {
    var routeName = k;
    var routeRegexp = new RegExp(routes[k]);

    // if connected ns matched with route regexp
    if (ns.match(routeRegexp)) {
      console.log('matched: '+routeName)

      // create new namespace (or use previously created)
      io.of(ns).on('connection', function (socket) {
        // fire event when socket connecting
        ev.emit('socket.connection route.'+routeName, socket);

        // @todo: add more if needed
        // on('message') -> ev.emit(...)
      });

      break;
    }
  }

  // when nothing matched
  // ...
});

// event when socket connected in 'user' namespace
ev.on('socket.connection route.user', function () {
  console.log('route[user] connecting..');
});

// event when socket connected in 'default' namespace
ev.on('socket.connection route.default', function () {
  console.log('route[default] connecting..');
});
```

I hope this will help you!

Comment: Can you please explain your example again. I'm doing the same thing and I think it's very useful, but I don't understand how you're doing things that you're doing.

Comment: I'm not sure when this was added, but now you can do it with a regex for your namespace name:
https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server-of-nsp

Answer (score 22):

I would use "rooms" to support your dynamic content.

**Server Side**

```
var server = require('http').createServer(),
    io     = require('socket.io')(server);


io.on('connection', function(socket){

  var room = socket.handshake['query']['r_var'];

  socket.join(room);
  console.log('user joined room #'+room);

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    socket.leave(room)
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });

  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.to(room).emit('chat message', msg);
  });

});

server.listen(3000);
```

**Client Side**

```
var socket_connect = function (room) {
    return io('localhost:3000', {
        query: 'r_var='+room
    });
}

var random_room = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
var socket      = socket_connect(random_room);

socket.emit('chat message', 'hello room #'+random_room);
....
```

Comment: After struggling with namespaces for hours, I finally solved my problems with rooms!

Comment: But then you can't add rooms to your rooms.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

As of version `2.1.1` I was able to make it work with this:

```
wss.of((nsp, query, next) => {
  const { token } = query;

  // Do your authentication or whatever here...

  // If success
  next(null, true);

}).on('connect', (socket) => {
  // socket connected to your namespace
});
```

Comment: Yes, it's in the docs just like that. But where do these parameters (nsp, query, next) come from? I don't get it.

Comment: OK I think I got it now. Using .of() with a regex or function makes it automagically listen to connects into a matching namespace-name and creates it then..

Answer (score 3):

**Server**

```
var MAX_CLIENTS = 5;
var namespace_queue = [];

function searchObjectOnArray(nameKey, myArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        if (myArray[i].id === nameKey) {
            return myArray[i];
        }
    }
}

function createNamespace(data){
    var ns = {
                //id: require('node-uuid')(),
                id : data.name,
                clients: 0, 
            };

    namespace_queue.push(ns);

    return ns;
}

createNamespace({name: 'primer'});

io.of('').on('connection', function(socket){     

    console.log('-' + socket.id);

    /// Welcome to the new client
    socket.emit('Welcome', {SocketId : socket.id});

    socket.on('JoinToApp', function (data, callback) {
        var namespaceToConnect = searchObjectOnArray(data.namespace, namespace_queue)
        if(namespaceToConnect.clients <= MAX_CLIENTS){
            var dynamicNamespace = io.of('/' + namespaceToConnect.id);

            dynamicNamespace.on('connection', function(ns_socket){
                    console.log('user connected to ' + namespaceToConnect.id);
                    dynamicNamespace.emit('hi', 'everyone!');
                });

            namespaceToConnect.clients++;  
        }          

        callback({namespaces:namespace_queue});
    })

    socket.on('createNamespace',function(data,join_cb){

        createNamespace(data);

        join_cb({message:'Namespace created'});
    }); 
});
```

**Client**

```
<input id="namespaceInput" type="text" placeholder="New namespace name">
<input id="namespaceToConnect" type="text" placeholder="namespace to connect">

<button onclick="javascript: createNamespace()">Create Namespace</button>
<button onclick="javascript: joinToNamespace()">Connect to Namespace</button>

<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = null;
   (function(){
       socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/');        
   })()

   function createNamespace(){
       var namespaceName = document.getElementById("namespaceInput").value;
       socket.emit('createNamespace', {name : namespaceName}, function(data){
           alert(data.message);
       })
   }

   function joinToNamespace(){
       var name = document.getElementById("namespaceToConnect").value;
       socket.emit('JoinToApp', {namespace: name}, function(data){
            console.log('Namespaces created:');
            console.log(data)

            var ns_socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/' + name);
            ns_socket.on('connect',function(){
                console.log('joined namespace ' + name);
            });

            ns_socket.on('hi', function(data){
                console.log('hi ' + data)
            })
        });

   }
</script>
```

More details on: https://ingcamilorodriguez.wordpress.com/2016/06/21/como-hacer-namespaces-dinamicos-en-socket-io/

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way.  Here is a socket.io subclass I created to solve the problem:

https://github.com/PencilCode/dynamic.io

That subclass adds dynamic namespaces as well as virtual hostname support (each host can go into its own namespace tree if you like).  That repo has some examples.

Here is a universal socket.io listener that listens to every namespace requested, and logs a message for every socket that connects.  You could listen to a different regexp to listen to any subset of namespaces.

It works with the standard socket.io client library without any modification.

```
var DynamicServer = require('dynamic.io');
io = DynamicServer({
    host: true,                     // Enable virtual host handling
    publicStatus: true              // Enable /socket.io/status page.
});
// Any number of namespace patterns can be set up.
// This is an example of a single catch-all pattern.
io.setupNamespace(/.*/, function(nsp) {
    nsp.on('connect', function(socket) {
        console.log('a socket connected on', nsp.fullname());
    });
    nsp.expire(function() {
        console.log(nsp.fullname(), 'is expiring');
    });
});
io.listen(8888);
```

Comment: Since you are keeping local mapping of namespace name against namespace instance.  How this will behave when we scale the instances from 1 to n. Can we save the nampespace instance in redis with it name for scaling .

Answer (score 0):

On newer versions you can use something like `io.of(/^\/\w+$/).on('connection', (socket)` where `/^\/\w+$/` is a regular expression that will allow connection if it is a match.

Here is a full example on how to use this to setup many namespaces, here I suppose the only concerne is preventing `emit` diffusion from reaching other namespaces.

```
const workspaces = {}
io.of(/^\/\w+$/).on('connection', (socket) => {
    const workspace = socket.nsp;
    const namespace = workspace.name;
    console.log("New Connection NameSpace", namespace);
    // you can test here if "namespace" is allowed to be used
    // if event handlers are set no need to got further
    if (workspaces[namespace]) return;
    // save workspace to prevent setting event handlers on each connection
    workspaces[namespace] = workspace;        
    workspace.on("connection", (socket) => {
        console.log(`${namespace} > connection from ${socket.id}`);
        // set the event handlers same as normal socket
        socket.on('event-1', (msg) => {
            console.log("event-1", msg);
        })
   })
 })
```