# Removing a specfic mapped route in Node.js at runtime removes static mapping?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Basing my function off of the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14034355/362536), I wrote this function to delete a route on a live site (using Express and Node).

```
function deleteRoute(url) {


 for (var i = app.routes.get.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   if (app.routes.get[i].path === "/" + url) {
     console.log(app.routes.get[i]);
     delete app.routes.get[i];
     console.log(app.routes.get)
   }
 }
}
```

However, when I run this it also seems to delete the routing to all of my static pages, which are declared at startup like this:

```
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/components'));
```

I've been wrestling this for a while and can't seem to get a grip on it. Can anyone out there help? Whenever I log app.routes.get before and after, it looks like the operation is done correctly.

Specifically, this is the error I get when reloading any static page after the route is removed:

```
 TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of undefined
```

Here is app.routes before the deletion:

```
 { get: 
  [ { path: '/',
   method: 'get',
   callbacks: [Object],
   keys: [],
   regexp: /^\/\/?$/i,
   params: [] },
 { path: '/index.html',
   method: 'get',
   callbacks: [Object],
   keys: [],
   regexp: /^\/index\.html\/?$/i,
   params: [] },
 { path: '/how_it_works.html',
   method: 'get',
   callbacks: [Object],
   keys: [],
   regexp: /^\/how_it_works\.html\/?$/i,
   params: [] },
 { path: '/about.html',
   method: 'get',
   callbacks: [Object],
   keys: [],
   regexp: /^\/about\.html\/?$/i,
   params: [] },
 { path: '/contribute.html',
   method: 'get',
   callbacks: [Object],
   keys: [],
   regexp: /^\/contribute\.html\/?$/i,
   params: [] },
 { path: '/contact.html',
   method: 'get',
   callbacks: [Object],
   keys: [],
   regexp: /^\/contact\.html\/?$/i,
   params: [] },
 { path: '/a.html',
   method: 'get',
   callbacks: [Object],
   keys: [],
   regexp: /^\/a\.html\/?$/i,
   params: [] } ],
post: 
 [ { path: '/admin-save.json',
   method: 'post',
   callbacks: [Object],
   keys: [],
   regexp: /^\/admin-save\.json\/?$/i,
   params: [] },
 { path: '/page-edit.json',
   method: 'post',
   callbacks: [Object],
   keys: [],
   regexp: /^\/page-edit\.json\/?$/i,
   params: [] },
 { path: '/get-pages.json',
   method: 'post',
   callbacks: [Object],
   keys: [],
   regexp: /^\/get-pages\.json\/?$/i,
   params: [] },
 { path: '/admin-delete.json',
   method: 'post',
   callbacks: [Object],
   keys: [],
   regexp: /^\/admin-delete\.json\/?$/i,
   params: [] } ] }
```

Here is it after:

```
{ get: 
 [ { path: '/',
   method: 'get',
   callbacks: [Object],
   keys: [],
   regexp: /^\/\/?$/i,
   params: [] },
 { path: '/index.html',
   method: 'get',
   callbacks: [Object],
   keys: [],
   regexp: /^\/index\.html\/?$/i,
   params: [] },
 { path: '/how_it_works.html',
   method: 'get',
   callbacks: [Object],
   keys: [],
   regexp: /^\/how_it_works\.html\/?$/i,
   params: [] },
 { path: '/about.html',
   method: 'get',
   callbacks: [Object],
   keys: [],
   regexp: /^\/about\.html\/?$/i,
   params: [] },
 { path: '/contribute.html',
   method: 'get',
   callbacks: [Object],
   keys: [],
   regexp: /^\/contribute\.html\/?$/i,
   params: [] },
 { path: '/contact.html',
   method: 'get',
   callbacks: [Object],
   keys: [],
   regexp: /^\/contact\.html\/?$/i,
   params: [] },
  ],
 post: 
  [ { path: '/admin-save.json',
   method: 'post',
   callbacks: [Object],
   keys: [],
   regexp: /^\/admin-save\.json\/?$/i,
   params: [] },
 { path: '/page-edit.json',
   method: 'post',
   callbacks: [Object],
   keys: [],
   regexp: /^\/page-edit\.json\/?$/i,
   params: [] },
 { path: '/get-pages.json',
   method: 'post',
   callbacks: [Object],
   keys: [],
   regexp: /^\/get-pages\.json\/?$/i,
   params: [] },
 { path: '/admin-delete.json',
   method: 'post',
   callbacks: [Object],
   keys: [],
   regexp: /^\/admin-delete\.json\/?$/i,
   params: [] } ] }
```

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(app.routes)` at the time `deleteRoute()` is called so we have something to work with?

Comment: @Brad added! Thank you so much for looking into this!

Comment: Any inclination as to why this would be happening? I'm so much at a loss, because it seems to be working if you read the logs only!

Comment: Where is that error being thrown? It isn't very useful without the stack trace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`delete` is for removing keys from objects, not for removing entries from arrays. By calling `delete`, you are essentially setting the value of that array location to `undefined`, so Express will still try to process that route when it looks through the routes.

Note your input before:

```
 { path: '/contact.html',
   method: 'get',
   callbacks: [Object],
   keys: [],
   regexp: /^\/contact\.html\/?$/i,
   params: [] },
 { path: '/a.html',
   method: 'get',
   callbacks: [Object],
   keys: [],
   regexp: /^\/a\.html\/?$/i,
   params: [] } ],
```

vs after:

```
 { path: '/contact.html',
   method: 'get',
   callbacks: [Object],
   keys: [],
   regexp: /^\/contact\.html\/?$/i,
   params: [] },
  ],
```

You erased the 'a.html' path, but note that there is still a `,` after the `contact.html` object. That is because the array entry is still there, it just has no value.

You need to use `splice` to remove the entries.

```
function deleteRoute(url) {
  for (var i = app.routes.get.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (app.routes.get[i].path === "/" + url) {
      app.routes.get.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

This method is also pointed out in the second answer of the question you linked to in your question.

Comment: This is perfect! I knew I was missing something small like this that threw the whole thing off. You're a lifesaver!