# Adding express routes asynchronously

Tags: node.js, express

In my Node.js/Express app, I want to load some routes to express asynchronously. To be precise, I want to retreive promotioncodes from mongodb, and based on those codes, create dynamic routes.

I currently have this code:

```
var promotion = require('../models/promotion');

promotion.list(function(promotions) {
    // Loop all promotions
    _.each(promotions, function(promo) {
        app.route(promo.get('path')).get(promotion.claim);
    });
});
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. After some debugging I found out that the routes actually are added to the route list, but because they are loaded asynchronously, they are added after the 'catch all' route that is added last. Which I found out by checking:

```
console.log(  app._router.stack  );
```

I've read some solutions that involve adding a catch all rule and handle route paths in that function, but honestly that doesn't sound too great. I'd like to keep using app.route() for my other routes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The catch all rule is still the best way of handling it. And you can still use app.route() for your other routes. Here is the example that could be used in app.js:

```
function r1(req,res) { res.status(202).end(); } //todo action logic
function r2(req,res) { res.status(202).end(); } //todo action logic
app.set("dynamic.routes", {"/r1":r1, "/r2":r2});

//this is dynamic routing function
function handleDynamicRoutes(req,res,next) {    
    var path = req.path;
    var routes = app.get("dynamic.routes");
    if (routes[path]) {
        routes[path](req,res);
    } else {
        next();
    }
}

app.all('*', handleDynamicRoutes);
app.use('/users', require('./routes/users')); //just an example
app.use('/documents', require('./routes/doucments')); //ditto
```

Obviously, you can change your dynamic.routes any time you want.
You can do it as flexible as you want, including using Route from express.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! After some more searching, I'm afraid you're right :). I was worrying about the the catch-all route maybe being bad for performance, because I read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344628/best-way-to-do-dynamic-routing-with-express-js-node-js. But after I re-read it, I realized the example in that anwswer is bad for performance because every call checks the database.