# Add Routes at Runtime (ExpressJs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, runtime

I would like to add routes at run time. I read that its possible but I am not so sure how. Currently I using the following code:

```
var app = express();

function CreateRoute(route){
app.use(route, require('./routes/customchat.js'));
}
```

And customchat looks like

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.route('/').get(function (req, res) {
var url =  req.baseUrl;
var roomname = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('_') + 1);
res.render('chat', { name: roomname , year: new Date().getFullYear().toString()});
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I call the method CreateRoute before I start listening it will link the route. But when I do it at runtime it wont create a new route.
My goal is to add routes add runtime. I will generate an path like /room_Date. And this should be added at runtime using the template customchat.

I am using express version 4.13.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What are you currently trying to do and what is not meeting your expected output?

Comment: @YuriZarubin Edit my post hope it is now clearer.

Comment: Perhaps you should take the approach suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344628/best-way-to-do-dynamic-routing-with-express-js-node-js You could modify the approach to trigger specific controller logic based on parsing the route, rather than rendering a particular view.

Answer (score 0):

`customchat.js` should called `customChat.js` and be

```
const customChat = (req, res) => {
  const { name } =  req.params;
  const year = new Date().getFullYear().toString();
  res.render('chat', { name , year });
}

module.exports = customChat
```

then when you create  your app

```
const express = require('express')
const customChat = require('./routes/customChat.js')
const app = express()

app.use('/chat/:name', customChat)
```

See [the official Express routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) docs for more information.