# Register new route at runtime in NodeJs/ExpressJs

Tags: node.js, express, dynamic-routing

I want to extend this open topic: [Add Routes at Runtime (ExpressJs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32800983/add-routes-at-runtime-expressjs) which sadly didn't help me enough.

I'm working on an application that allows the creation of different API's that runs on NodeJs. The UI looks like this:

[image: new rule with two endpoints (GET,POST)]

As you can see, this piece of code contains two endpoints (GET, POST) and as soon as I press "*Save*", it creates a .js file located in a path where the Nodejs application is looking for its endpoints (e.g: myProject\dynamicRoutes\rule_test.js).

The problem that I have is that being that the Nodejs server is running while I'm developing the code, I'm not able to invoke these new endpoints **unless I restart the server once again (and ExpressJs detects the file)**.

Is there a way to register new routes while the
NodeJs (ExpressJs) is running?

I tried to do the following things with no luck:

**app.js**

This works if the server is restarted. I tried to include this library ([express-dynamic-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-dynamic-router), but not working at runtime.)

```
//this is dynamic routing function
function handleDynamicRoutes(req,res,next) {    
    var path = req.path; //http://localhost:8080/api/rule_test
    //LoadModules(path)
    var controllerPath = path.replace("/api/", "./dynamicRoutes/");
    var dynamicController = require(controllerPath);
    dynamicRouter.index(dynamicController[req.method]).register(app);
    dynamicController[req.method] = function(req, res) {
       //invocation
    }

    next();
}

app.all('*', handleDynamicRoutes);
```

Finally, I readed this article ([#NodeJS / #ExpressJS: Adding routes dynamically at runtime](https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/expressjs-dynamic-runtime-routing/)), but I couldn't figure out how this can help me.

I believe that this could be possible somehow, but I feel a bit lost. Anyone knows how can I achieve this? I'm getting a CANNOT GET error, after each file creation.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer: please know that it is considered as bad design in terms of stability and security to allow the user or even administrator to inject executable code via web forms. Treat this thread as academic discussion and don't use this code in production!**

---

Look at this simple example which adds new route in runtime:

`app.get('/subpage', (req, res) => res.send('Hello subpage'))`

So basically new route is being registered when app.get is called, no need to walk through routes directory.

All you need to do is simply load your newly created module and pass your app to module.exports function to register new routes. I guess this one-liner should work just fine (not tested):

`require('path/to/new/module')(app)`

Comment: Let me check it. Don't worry about the disclaimer, because it's all considered by using a login on the page that allows the user to access the showed page.

Comment: the problem that I see, is that for some reason, I can't reach the new file which contains the app.get() function. I'm getting a 404, because the file is not recognized.

Comment: Hi @MauroBilotti, you managed to solve this one ? I got into a similar situation. It'd be good to have a new insight. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Is req.params enough for you?

```
app.get('/basebath/:path, (req,res) => {
  const content = require('content/' + req.params.path);
  res.send(content);
});
```

So the user can enter whatever after /basepath, for example

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/basepath/bergur
```

The router would then try to get the file content/bergur.js
and send it's contents.

Comment: As I said, the creation of these files happens at runtime, and I'm using app.all('*',handleDynamicRoutes) to do something like you propose. The problem with this approach is that I get a 404 Not Found on the new file. So it didn't help me. Thanks anyway!