# Express & Socket.io Route parroting/copying/sharing

Tags: node.js, routes, express, socket.io

I'm working with expressjs and socket.io in nodejs. I'm looking into assign identical route handlers to requests made in either HTTP or via websockets/socket.io.

For instance:

```
var responder = function(req, res){
  req.params //<-- {id: 'something...'}
}
app.get('/foo/:id', responder);
io.on('/foo/:id', responder);
```

socket.io doesn't appear to have this type of routing functionality. Does anyone know of a library/module to help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several options.

- If you'd like to keep using [express](/questions/tagged/express), check out [express.io](https://github.com/techpines/express.io).
- If you don't mind using something a bit different, [sails](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails) lets you do this sort of thing as well.

(**Update**: sails now uses express too)

Both have been used in production successfully.

Note that routing is also pretty simple to implement on your own. If you check out [how express do it](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/lib/router) I'm sure you'll be able to figure out a slim implementation that would match you needs.

Good luck! Let me know what you ended up using and how it worked for you.

Comment: Hey Benjamin thanks for your response. I'm familiar with express.io but it doesn't seem to be able to match routes 1:1 - instead it seems to be able to forward an http request to a socket.io event handler function. And sails looks great but it's not quite there yet for my needs (for instance, no relationships between their models, and no way to configure socket.io without hacking the original source)

Comment: What I think I'm going to try now is setting up a routing table with flatiron-director (https://github.com/flatiron/director#api-documentation), abstracting a response method to handle returning JSON to either http or websocket requests, and calling .dispatch() to trigger my routes.

I'll tell you how this goes and I'll create a github gist for it as well.

Comment: I'm sorry neither is a great fit for your needs. These are the two best options out there today. Handling routing yourself is not too complicated, I wouldn't telling you how to possibly implement that, flatiron might indeed also be worth checking out (No personal experience with it, looks interesting).

Comment: Hey Benjamin, I've ditched flatiron/director namely because I realized I can accomplish the same thing with the router baked into express.io
https://gist.github.com/cflynn07/5293090
^Lines 63 - 79 are where I try to create a uniform interface for responding to requests with JSON over HTTP or socket.io

I'm going to use this with a custom JS helper method on the client.