# Support static files and websockets on the same port in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have set up a [Websocket server](https://github.com/OvalBit/Sigma/blob/master/server/server.js) on port 8888, using Node.js. I also have an interface for that which interacts with the Websocket backend (chat server).

How do I also serve static files ( index.html, CSS/JS files) on the same port (when the server is accessed using a browser GET request)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use ExpressJS and Socket.io on a same port?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235406/how-to-use-expressjs-and-socket-io-on-a-same-port)

Comment: @iandotkelly I believe after the edit, the question should open again. The possibly duplicate question is: 1. Asking in the context of a specific framework, 2. does not ask about static files.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you don't want to use `socket.io`, but the [`websocket`](https://npmjs.org/package/websocket) package, you can use it in combination with [Express](http://expressjs.com) like this:

```
// app.js
var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
var express         = require('express');
var app             = express();
var server          = app.listen(8888);
var wsServer        = new WebSocketServer({ httpServer : server });

// this will make Express serve your static files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// the rest of your code
wsServer.on('request', function(r) { ...
```

`express.static` will take care of serving your HTML/CSS/JS files. The argument you pass is the directory where those files are located (in this case, the directory `public/` relative to where `app.js` is located).

Comment: Thanks, perfect. I did this, and it worked, but in my client js file, I tried changing the `ws://` address of the server from the public IP to localhost, but it didn't work. Is this just not possible, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try using `new WebSocket('ws://' + location.host)` in your client file.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some good gist's how the set up a websocket server incl. serving an webapp for that:

- https://gist.github.com/johnhunter/1456613 (express.js + socket.io)
- https://gist.github.com/damianb/4190316 (expressjs + socket.io + passport + redis)

Here are also similar questions:

- [How to use ExpressJS and Socket.io on a same port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235406/how-to-use-expressjs-and-socket-io-on-a-same-port)
- [Express & Socket.io Route parroting/copying/sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732678/express-socket-io-route-parroting-copying-sharing)