# Nodejs "ws" Websocket Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am using creating an online game with nodejs and websockets. As websocket library I am using the module "ws". I am not using nodejs to run an HTTP server I am using apache + php to host the website/client and nodejs I only running as an websocket server.

As far as I know to open a websocket connection (on port 443) an handshake must be made in another port. I am using port 3000 in my case (since on port 80 its my apache server running).

On my server.js file (the file where nodejs starts) I am using this code to initialize the websocket server:

```
var PORT = 3000;
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var wsServer = new WebSocketServer({ port: PORT });
```

And when is visit www.mywebsite.com:3000 I get this text message "Upgrade Required". What I would like to do was to print the number of clients connected to the server when I access that port. Is it possible to make since I am using the "ws" module native server?

Thanks, if you did not understand my question clearly please tell me on the comments.

Comment: Its not a duplicate from that question. Because I have an HTTP server. What I want is to display the number of online clients on the PORT 3000 when the browser is not trying to create a websocket handshake. This way I don´t have to keep 2 servers on NodeJS and I will save some CPU. (I don´t think it is worth creating another server just to print a number)

Comment: Also my HTTP server that is running apache is in one machine with one IP and then from my website you select the server where you want to establish a websocket connection (based on your location). What I need now is a way to print the number of clients in each server and then display it on my homepage. I could do it using websockets but I had to open a websocket connection to each server and then request the number of clients online. So I thought it would be easier just print the number on the Port 3000

Comment: Well, then you are probably searching for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919947/serve-websocket-and-http-server-at-same-address-on-node-js …

Comment: At least, the ws WebsocketServer does not seem to provide an API for an alternative if the upgrading is not possible

Comment: Will it be the same thing in terms of CPU usage? Using the native WS server or passing a reference to a HTTP server?

Comment: Try it out? Difference should be minimal...

Comment: I am just asking because my game server takes a lot of CPU so I want to reduce the usage in stuff like this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122599/discussion-between-daniel-oliveira-and-bwoebi).

Answer (score 1):

I've also met the same problem.
May be the problem of ws module. 
Last, I use http module to write it myself