# Node.js with express and websocket giving error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket

So I am trying to set up a website that also has websockets where both the http-server and the websocket listens on the same port:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


wss = new WebSocket.Server({server : app});

app.get('/', function(req, res){

    res.send('hello world!');
});


wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
  });

  ws.send('some text');
});


app.listen(8080, function(){

    console.log('app started');
});
```

If I then load the servers website in chrome-browser I am greeted with "hello world!". So far so good. But if I open up the webconsole and try to connect with

```
var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("ws://192.10.10.30:8080");
```

I get the following errormessage:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.10.10.30:8080/' failed: Error
>   during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

My first thought was, do I have to explicitly declare an http-server ?

But I read this post
[Serve WebSocket and HTTP server at same address on Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919947/serve-websocket-and-http-server-at-same-address-on-node-js) and there was no http-server explicitly declared. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're passing an Express app instance as `server`, which should be an HTTP/HTTPS server instance. Such an instance is returned by `app.listen`:

```
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log('app started');
});

wss = new WebSocket.Server({server : server});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue on a Windows machine and discovered the reason was IIS did not have the WebSocket Protocol turned on. Ensure IIS on the machine supports WebSocket:
Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off.
Expand Internet Information Services, expand World Wide Web Services, expand Application Development Features, and then ensure **WebSocket Protocol** is checked.

Comment: many many thanks , this has actually solve my problem