# Join a Namespace Room from different Namespace

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, namespaces

So, pretty much what i asked, how can i join a namespace room being "inside" different namespace?

```
var mainNamespace = io.of('/main');
var chatNamespace = io.of('/chat');

mainNamespace.on("connection", function (socket) {

    socket.on("somethingHappens", function () {
        // i thought i could do this
        chatNamespace.join("coolRoom", function(){
           console.log("yey i joined the room!");
        })
    });
}
```

Can i obtain this somehow?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it easily. Unlike rooms, namespaces are not dynamic and determined on connection. For example, you can call io.connect('/main'); in the front-end.

Once connection is made, the socket belongs to the namespace it is connected to.

The idea of [dynamic namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143945/dynamic-namespaces-socket-io) has been around for a while and there are some implementation and modules.

Answer (score 0):

**Xplouder** don't have much more to add than my original comment on github (from 2012) since I don't use that library any more.

ref: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/285#issuecomment-8962287

I *do* recall that the variable `socket` *had* a property named `namespace` which *was* a reference to the namespace the socket is **currently** in. I cannot speak for changes to the API since 2012.

The following commands should give you more of an idea of what's happening internally:

```
console.log( socket.namespace === mainNamespace );
console.log( socket.namespace.name );
console.log( socket.rooms );
```

I'd suggest trying to change the `socket.namespace` manually, such as:

> socket.namespace = chatNamespace;

If you fail to do this then I think the socket will join `/main/coolRoom` rather than `/chat/coolRoom` as you expected.

For posterity if anyone else is having issues I would suggest logging the `console.log` statements above and observing how the *current* namespace name affects the `.join()` method.

Comment: Sadly it do not work anymore, had to merge the two namespaces i had to solve this... Thank you anyway. :)