# Socket.IO define namespace in runtime

Tags: node.js, socket.io

In socket.IO there are 2 ways to send message to users separately: rooms and namespaces. In my project I need both of them - namespaces to divide users of different applications and rooms for each namespace for private messages and other specific stuff.

It's quite easy to create rooms directly in runtime. But is it possible to do the same trick with namespaces? I'd like to do something like this:

```
 io.of(*someFunctionToCreateNameSpaceInRuntime*) 
 .on('connection', function (socket) {
     socket.emit(***);
 });
```

There is very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004616/has-anyone-successfully-implemented-a-dynamic-namespace-in-node-socket-io), but id doesn't work now. Is it possible to send *namespace name* with params and store it somewhere before connection event fires?

Thanks for any advise.